# ESLint: Avoid nesting of ternary expressions

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, eslint

I have this function:

```
foo(number) {
    this.navDropdowns = this.navDropdowns.map((item, index) =>
      (index === number
        ? item ? true : !item
        : false));
  },
```

ESLint doesn't allow to nest my expressions indicating that there is something wrong with `index`. Any guess how to avoid this?

Comment: I don't like it either. :) Don't nest your ternaries, no more eslint warning/error. Or, turn off the eslint rule. Eslint doesn't stop you from doing it either way.

Comment: More brackets would fix it, but you really shouldn't.  Just pretty it up instead of trying to make it as small as possible.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see any other solution... Thank you,  guys!

Comment: `item ? true : !item` this is a bit useless. If item is truthy then true, other wise convert the falsey to true? You may as well use `(item, index) => index === number`